# How to see the run time values of observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

consider the below class which receive a parameter from route component

```
export class customerEntryPoint  {

readonly customerId$: Observable<string>;

constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {

this.customerId$ = route.querparams.pipe(
                    filter(params => params.customerId?.length > 0),
                    filter(params => params.customerId))l

console.log(this.customerId$)
```

Question. The above code is fine but the question is how can i view the value using the console.log statement or is their a better approach to view the values run time

}

Comment: You might find this article interesting: https://blog.angular-university.io/debug-rxjs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put console log in a side effect `tap` operator at desired step

```
       route.querparams.pipe(
                filter(params => params.customerId?.length > 0),
                filter(params => params.customerId),
                tap(console.log))
```